# InfoPath 2010 rich text box control not working in chrome browser

Tags: infopath, rich-text, chrome

We have a InfoPath form which has multiple rich box controls. Everything works perfectly when we go and create a new form in IE. But when users trying to do the same through chrome the rich text box control is giving error. Is there any way we can eradicate this error and make this thing work in chrome browser.

[image]

Comment: AFAIK, rich text box only works with IE, it adds a lot of stuff besides the text itself. Not to say that regular textbox works well with chrome either. If you can't control your user groups choice of browser, then don't use InfoPath imo. From what I can read the 2016 version _might_ be better at this..

Comment: Thanks Tobb for the info provided.We have updated this to our users.

Comment: The rich text control is still editable in Firefox even though it complains that there is no support for rich text. It defaults to plain text. Is there a way to make Chrome stop complaining and just edit the text in plain text for these controls like you can in Firefox?